# SD card not detected with Raspberry Pi imager on Chromebook

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, sd-card

I decided I would install the Ubuntu server on the Raspberry Pi.

I have the Raspberry Pi imager installed on my Chromebook, but when I insert my micro SD card in the Chromebook’s SD card slot, the Raspberry Pi imager doesn't show any SD card on the list.

Here is a screenshot:

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Which OS are running in the Chromebook? Supposedly the Raspeberry Pi Imager works on Debian/Ubuntu x86 (and x86_64), not ARM, and also desktop versions of Windows or MacOS. It has no version that runs directly on ChromeOS. And, perhaps, more important, did you install the SNAP version? If so (and assuming Ubuntu) then you should search for it in the Ubuntu Software app, click permissions and allow mass storage devices. Without this permissions no snap app can access external media.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I don't directly run the raspberry pi imager on the chromebook, actually I run it on the linux terminal which can be added in the Chrome OS settings. As for the os that the linux addition uses, it uses a version of debian. (Debian 10, I think). Also, if I try to install the raspberry pi imager with snap, I get this error: `error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs": mount:
       /tmp/sanity-mountpoint-175359566: mount failed: Operation not permitted.`

Comment: Well, if you didn't install the snap version then the limitations/permissions issue isn't applicable. But what can be happening is some sort of isolation similar to a virtual machine (just guessing, I really don't know).

Answer (score -1):

I HAVE THE ANSWER
first you need to have a micro sd or sd card adapter to usb
secondly you need to go in the linux settings on the settings app and activate the adapter and now normally if you go on rpi imager your sd card will be showed

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).